# ng lint Could not find custom rule directory: codelyzer with Angular CLI on gitlab CI

Tags: angular, typescript, gitlab, lint

`ng lint` fails on Gitlab CI with the error message `An unhandled exception occurred: Failed to load /builds/trade-up/trade-up/common/projects/trade-up-common/tslint.json: Could not find custom rule directory: codelyzer`.

`ng lint` is running without issues on my local machine but failing on gitlab CI.

In the trade-up-common package, I have added `tslint.json` to the `.npmignore` file.
Codelyzer is included in the dependencies of both the main angular app and the common package.

Answer (score 5):

You have to install codelyzer

```
npm install codelyzer
```

then define in the rules directory :

```
 "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. I've tried this approach in both the main app and inside the common package, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually caused by a bad import. The parent app was referencing a local version of my custom package instead of the one published to `npm`.